# Heroku app does not start (No such file or directory /usr/bin/env: ruby), Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ubuntu-14.04

I'm aiming to implement a [Scrivito](https://scrivito.com) test app and deploy it to Heroku. I am able to push to Heroku successfully, but when I open the Heroku app, I receive the following error in my Heroku logs.

```
2016-09-19T18:02:37.970943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-19T18:02:43.815636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command "bin/rails server -p 44169 -e production" : No such file or directory00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby
2016-09-19T18:02:45.897524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-09-19T18:02:45.913351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-19T18:21:39.994431+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by x@gmail.com
2016-09-19T18:21:39.994242+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 72a4fb2 by x@gmail.com
2016-09-19T18:21:40.329657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-19T18:21:40.846263+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-09-19T18:21:40.846272+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-09-19T18:21:52.697002+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command "bin/rails server -p 5064 -e production": No such file or directory00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby
2016-09-19T18:21:54.219622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-09-19T18:21:54.249853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-19T18:21:54.250802+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-19T18:21:59.216745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command "bin/rails server -p 17564 -e production": No such file or directory00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby
2016-09-19T18:22:01.412414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-09-19T18:22:01.457536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-19T18:22:02.108887+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=scrivitoexampleapp.herokuapp.com request_id=b46afd2a-7fc1-462f-acd5-876551be1aa3 fwd="70.171.137.175" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-19T18:22:02.400312+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=scrivitoexampleapp.herokuapp.com request_id=d5321dcc-56f0-474a-a7c3-8ff420ad851b fwd="70.171.137.175" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

"usr/bin/env ruby" is found in four files in my app:

```
C:\Users\Laura\Documents\railsVM\scrivito_example_app\bin\bundle:
   1: #!/usr/bin/env ruby
   2  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
   3  load Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle')

C:\Users\Laura\Documents\railsVM\scrivito_example_app\bin\rails:
   1: #!/usr/bin/env ruby
   2  APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
   3  require_relative '../config/boot'

C:\Users\Laura\Documents\railsVM\scrivito_example_app\bin\rake:
   1: #!/usr/bin/env ruby
   2  require_relative '../config/boot'
   3  require 'rake'

C:\Users\Laura\Documents\railsVM\scrivito_example_app\bin\setup:
   1: #!/usr/bin/env ruby
   2  require 'pathname'
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.3.0"

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'scrivito', '1.5.1'
gem 'scrivito_advanced_editors'
gem 'secure_headers'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end`
```

I am on Windows 10 running Ubuntu 14.04.

I am wondering if this has to do with the fact that I recently updated to Rails 5, but Scrivito does not yet support it. I've pushed to Heroku both with and without a Ruby version specified, thinking that was the issue. None of the other questions on this topic seem to resolve my issue.

Comment: **UPDATE:**
I've pushed an updated Gemfile to Heroku now which includes Ruby 2.3.1.  
When I run `heroku run "ruby -v"` I receive the results: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`.  
Error is still occurring in Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue with all this was that on my Windows / Vagrant environment, the line breaks in the bin folder were mixed up. I ran `rake rails:update:bin` and pushed the changes through and all's well to run it on Heroku!

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to `ruby 2.3.1` and run `heroku run "ruby -v"` to ensure versions match.

Comment: Sorry, @cema-sp, I'm so new with all this - can you clarify how I switch to `ruby 2.3.1`? I do now have it installed (I didn't realize Ruby doesn't automatically update with `bundle update`.

Comment: You may use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), it is easy to install and use. Bundler only updates gems.
Anyway, try running `heroku run "ruby -v"` in your heroku project directory to check ruby version on the server. It should be 2.3.1 AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this command and fixed this problem for me

```
$ dos2unix bin/bundle bin/rake bin/rails
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

and

```
rake update:bin
```

did not work for me for some reason. So I ran

```
rake app:update
```

instead and then iteratively force-replaced each bin file while skipping the other configuration files. It is not a perfect solution but it works.

NOTE: *(I would have added this as a comment to the answer but right now I don't have enough reputation to add comments.)*