# `heroku open` and `heroku run rake db:migrate` not working ("No such file or directory")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 7 app and as of my most recent commit, the entire Heroku production site errors regardless of what page I'm trying to access.

Of course, I tried to do `heroku logs -t` to figure out what happened but when I try to do command line commands for `heroku` (such as `heroku logs`, `heroku open`, or `heroku run rake db:migrate`) I am met with the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/8.5.0/lib/client/bin/heroku: line 16: /usr/local/Cellar/heroku/8.5.0/lib/client/bin/../8.7.1-3f5e369/bin/heroku: No such file or directory
```

As recommended in posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581924/heroku-app-does-not-start-no-such-file-or-directory-usr-bin-env-ruby-ubuntu), I have tried `rake rails:update:bin`, but it errors and recommends `Did you mean?  app:update:bin`...which does run successfully but does not fix my heroku error.

Has anyone else had this problem?  I'm not sure what changes I could have made that caused it so suddenly because the push in question didn't change any config variables or settings other than normal content update stuff.

I would check my Heroku logs or see if I could run `heroku run rails c`....but I can't because I get the same error....

**EDIT:**  If I rollback my most recent update I am able to actually see my Heroku site without the entire thing throwing an error, but I still can't run any command line `heroku` commands and any subsequent pushes break the entire production site again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is not happening at your repo level, but within the script file on your local machine that executes when you call `heroku` from the command line. I encountered something similar yesterday after accessing Heroku for the first time in a while.

The script is trying to locate a local directory where all its resources are stored; it decides everything should be in a particular location, but there's nothing there when it goes to look.

I executed the following commands, after which everything was back to normal:

```bash
brew uninstall heroku
brew cleanup # this may not be necessary, but I don't have a record of what would happen if I hadn't run it
brew install heroku
heroku auth:login # to re-authenticate with heroku
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this was all it took:

```
brew reinstall heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to also delete some files manually:

```
brew uninstall heroku
rm ~/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku*
rm '/usr/local/bin/heroku'
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
heroku auth:login
```